# Нужна ли запятая после "не важно"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, бсп

Он выполнил свою задачу, и не важно(,) насколько правильно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Он выполнил свою задачу, и не важно, насколько правильно.*

Запятая нужна для разделения безличного предложения "***и не важно***" и неполного предложения "***насколько правильно*** [он выполнил]".